# Not able to send value to Send-MailMessage with PowerShell Pipeline

Tags: powershell

I am using below PowerShell to pass subject parameter to Send-MailMessage but its not working. Even after passing subject value its still asks for an input for Subject

```
Get-Date | Select-Object @{Name='Subject';Expression={$_.DateTime}} | Send-MailMessage -From 'myemail@mydomain.com' -To 'myemail@mydomain.com' -SmtpServer 'mysmptserver.COM'
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The `Subject` parameter of `Send-MailMessage` does *not* accept pipeline input:

```
PS ~> Get-Help Send-MailMessage -Parameter Subject

-Subject <string>

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    1
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Parameter set name           (All)
    Aliases                      sub
    Dynamic?                     false
```

Pipe your data to `ForEach-Object` and call `Send-MailMessage` on each iteration instead:

```sh
Get-Date | Select-Object @{Name='Subject';Expression={$_.DateTime}} | ForEach-Object {
  Send-MailMessage -Subject $_ -From 'myemail@mydomain.com' -To 'myemail@mydomain.com' -SmtpServer 'mysmptserver.COM' 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mathias for quick response. Still its not working and asking for value for subject. Also looked at online documentation and it says Accept pipeline input to True.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: @RaviKhambhati My mistake, I forgot to add `-Subject $_`, answer has been updated now, try again :)

Comment: Thanks @Mathias for the update. Does this mean the documentation on Microsoft is incorrect?

Comment: @RaviKhambhati You're looking at the documentation for PowerShell 7.2, check out the docs for [Windows PowerShell 5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1#parameters) :)